# Are database triggers the way to go with this business logic

Tags: database, caching, triggers, business-logic

I am currently implementing some "reports" in my application that aggregate a huge amount of information taken from the database : each cell of a table comes from the total of another table, for which each cell comes from the total of another table, etc.
The report should always show the most recent data to the user : each data changing anywhere in the software and reports have to be up to date.

I end up with too much SQL generated.

I tried to cache (in DB) intermediate results and tables, which works. But then anywhere in the app where a data can be changed, I have to recompute the cache which is ending in `recomputeCache()` calls in too many places (remember, this is to maintain absolute up to date reports).

DBMS triggers could work : a trigger on a table computing the next one, which holds a trigger computing the next, etc.
But I'm afraid of triggers :

- What about complexity ? The code doing the computing is pretty big and "smart" : 200 lines of .NET full of syntactic sugar will become 500 of PL/SQL.
- What about maintenability ? Won't the PL/SQL be harder to find, to read, to understand, to modify, to debug, etc. ?
- What about business logic encapsulation ? Shouldn't this computing belong to the business logic layer ?

I am listening to any advice helping me to choose between "typical" software caching (and I'll try to find a smart cache recomputing strategy) and triggers-based tables recomputation (and maybe sacrifice software best practices and maintenability ?)...

Thank you !

Comment: Can you use materialized views with auto-update?

Answer (score 0):

For your reports I would first try to use views. The view will always be up to date as its just a view into the up-to-date data of the underlying tables. This will save you the complexity and some of the headaches associated with triggers you pointed out.

Example:

```
CREATE VIEW report AS
SELECT 'sales' AS name, (SELECT sum(sales) FROM sales) AS value
UNION ALL
SELECT 'expenses' AS name, (SELECT sum(expenses) FROM expenses) AS value
```

If the performance of the view isn't sufficient enough, then you could indeed look into triggers and be smarter about aggregating totaling without having to re-read all records. But I'd start with a view first as your simplest option.

Comment: The query defining the view would be too long to execute each time, but as Vaibhav Desai said, materialized view could resolve this.
Still, the amount of data to agregate is huge and I don't know if I will be able to write it as a single SQL query.
I'll dig into that, thank you.